# "Error Loading USE or USELSX" when trying to import Script Library

Tags: lotus-domino

I get this error when trying to import a script library from my project.

The Script Library does not use Java and [I'm not Turkish](http://lotusnotus.com/lotusnotus_en.nsf/dx/mystery-solved-error-loading-use-or-uselsx-module.htm). Also, recompiling did not help and it is not LSX.

I even removed the whole code from it and still get the problem. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the Domino Designer.

We have this problem here sometimes and it usually does the trick. It is easy to forget the obvious things sometimes.

Comment: You are answering your own question with a "try this". That's strange :-)